# C++ error: no matching function for call to 'print_size'

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, auto

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void print_size(std::vector<T> a)
{
    std::cout << a.size() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3};
    print_size(v);

    auto w = {1, 2, 3};
    // print_size(w); // error: no matching function for call to 'print_size'
                      // candidate template ignored: could not match 'vector' against 'initializer_list'
}
```

...which compiles and runs without any issues. But if I enable the commented-out line, it produces the error `no matching function for call to 'print_size'`.

I would like to know what is the correct way to write this code in C++11 and later versions.

Comment: ` since C++11 we should try to use auto everywhere` - no. AAA is a terrible idea. The correct and idiomatic way in C++11 is `std::vector<int> w{1, 2, 3};` and `std::vector w{1, 2, 3}` in C++17.

Comment: For AAA, `auto w = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};`...

Comment: Your `auto w` is automatically recognized as `initializer_list`, which is reasonable. You cannot expect compiler to recognize it as `std::vector<int>`, because `{x, x, x}` is not necessarily a `vector` (might be any kind of container or a raw array) and `x` is not necessarily an `int`.

Comment: Why is providing a code that does not work and asking for a way to fix it opinion-based? I believe there would be at most two or three ways to fix it. If those two or three ways are documented in an answer, it should be an objective answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `auto w = {1, 2, 3};` the type of `w` will be `std::initializer_list<int>`, and `print_size(w);` fails because template parameter `T` can't be deduced; [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions) does not consider implicit conversions.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

You can specify template argument explicitly,

```
print_size<int>(w);
```

Or you can make `w` to be a `std::vector<int>` instead; and if you persist using `auto` you need to specify the type explicitly.

```
auto w = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};
print_size(w);
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is argument type of `print_size`.
Your `auto w = {1, 2, 3};` has type `std::initializer_list<int>` and this doesn't match to a `vector<T>`, there is no automatic conversion.

So you can correct `print_size` this way:

```
template<class T>
void print_size(std::initializer_list<T> a)
{
    std::cout << a.size() << '\n';
}
```

Or even better change how template is parametrized:

```
template<class T>
void print_size(const T& a)
{
    std::cout << a.size() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without C++17 deduction guides the compiler cannot deduce `T` for `std::vector<T>` parameter from argument of type `std::initializer_list<T>`, unfortunately.

I would suggest adding an overload for `print_size(std::initializer_list<T> const&)`.

Answer (score 0):

casting w would be a solution

```
    print_size((std::vector<int>)w);
```

Comment: The cast will just invoke the constructor, so using `std::vector<int>{w}` instead would be more direct.